# Functional equation over positive integers: $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) + 3(x + y)\sqrt[3]{f(x)f(y)}$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions from positive integers to positive integers such that $$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) + 3(x + y)\sqrt[3]{f(x)f(y)}$$ for all positive integers $x$ and $y$.

My progress so far:
We claim that the unique solution is $$f(x) \equiv x^3.$$ Plugging this in, this works because $$(x + y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3(x + y)xy$$ is true after expanding.

We wish to show that this is the only valid solution. Plug in $(x, x)$ to get $$f(2x) = 2f(x) + 6x\sqrt[3]{f(x)^2}.$$ So, $$\frac{f(2x) - 2f(x)}{6x} = f(x)^{2/3}.$$ The left-hand side is a rational number. Then, since $f(x)$ is an integer, $f(x)^{2/3}$ can only be a rational number if $f(x)$ is a perfect cube. So, we can define a new function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{f(x)}$.

Then, $g$ must satisfy the equation $$g(x + y)^3 = g(x)^3 + g(y)^3 + 3(x + y)g(x)g(y),$$ and we wish to show that $g(x) \equiv x$. Notice that if we can find the value of $g(1)$, then by induction, we will be able to use the above condition to solve for $g$ for all positive integers.

Plug in $(1, 1)$: $$g(2)^3 = 2g(1)^3 + 6g(1)^2.$$ Plug in $(2, 1)$: $$g(3)^3 = g(2)^3 + g(1)^3 + 9g(2)g(1).$$ Plug in $(2, 2)$ and $(3, 1)$: $$g(4)^3 = 2g(2)^3 + 12g(2)^2 = g(3)^3 + g(1)^3 + 12g(3)g(1).$$

Dilemma: This should be solvable to get $g(1) = 1$, but it seems very difficult. Maybe there are some number-theoretic approaches to show that $g(1) = 1$, using the fact that $g$ is defined over the natural numbers?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is also a solution, and there can be others.

Comment: I meant that $f(x)$ takes in positive integers and outputs positive integers, in which case $f(x) \equiv x^3$ should be unique. Over all integers or the reals, the answer may be different.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x%2By)%3Df(x)%2Bf(y)%2B3(x%2By)%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bf(x)f(y)%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20integers&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Easy Basic FE](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1880896p12796750), where a posted answer there claims that, even over the reals, the only solutions are $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: Yes, I will look over that, thank you. That does not solve my problem though, because that solution used the value of $f(0)$ to solve which I cannot do. That is, solving over $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ would generalize my problem, but solving over $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ would not be a generalization.

Comment: No responses from anyone?

Comment: IIRC this question was asked on AoPS some days back, with the same working, so I assume it was asked by you? It had answers there.